# google maps street view avaliable

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am working with streetview google maps found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama

I can't seem to find if there is a way to determine if Street View imagery is available at the specified position?

I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem what and what you did to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it thanks

Use the

google.maps.StreetViewStatus

class